# Anyone know of a good SNPP/WCTP Gateway i can use in my application?

Tags: paging, sms-gateway

I need my application to receive SNPP & WCTP messages from clients arround the world...

and i don't won't to implement the full RFC on my own, do you know where it is possible to download some application/service that can perform as SNPP/WCTP Gateway and convert the protocol from snpp/wctp to http or something like that...which is more easy to parse?

I need something I can trust that it is implementing the protocol with no mistakes.
also 2-way paging support is needed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a WCTP [reference](http://content.arch.com/developer/DevCon2001/DevCon2001.pdf) and [implementation](http://content.arch.com/developer/downloads.html) written in Java and C and there are some [commercial](http://www.air-messenger-wctp-5-0-0.com-about.com/) applications.  [InfoRad](http://www.inforad.com/) also makes paging software.

Answer (score 1):

Also looking 2016.

http://www.sendpage.org/ - perl
- sendpage-server available in ubuntu, seem to work.